# correct way to create twitter heron project using intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-storm, heron

I'm trying to start a heron project (or port existing storm project) using IntelliJ IDEA but unfortunately I can't make it work.

I have tested all the suggested instructions in [Heron Docs](https://twitter.github.io/heron/) to [upgrade from storm](https://twitter.github.io/heron/docs/upgrade-storm-to-heron) but after changing `POM.xml` file based on documentation, i get bunch of `cannot find symbol` from basic heron classes and methods while compiling with maven and adding library Jars doesn't help (like it used to with storm).

I Also tried to use `setup-intellij.sh` script to make an intellij project but unfortunately it stops with errors:

```
null failed: _pex failed: error executing command
bazel-out/local_linux-fastbuild/bin/3rdparty/pex/_pex --entry-point heron.shell.src.python.main bazel-out/local_linux-fastbuild/bin/heron/shell/src/python/heron-shell.pex ...
(remaining 1 argument(s) skipped)
```

I'm wondering what is the easiest way to create a working project using intelliJ IDEA.

Do I have to add storm libraries as well as heron libraries to intelliJ? how can I attach required libraries so it can compile correctly?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `backtype.storm.*` instead of `com.twitter.heron.api.*` to import classes.
These packages all exist in heron library.
Just need to add the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twitter.heron</groupId>
        <artifactId>heron-storm</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a heron project running in IntellJ, [here](https://github.com/streamlio/heron-java-streamlet-api-example).
The pom.xml content is:

```
<groupId>io.streaml.heron.streamlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>heron-java-streamlet-api-example</artifactId>
    <version>latest</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <heron.version>0.17.2</heron.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter.heron</groupId>
            <artifactId>heron-api</artifactId>
            <version>${heron.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass></mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
```